# Run task for defined time

Tags: android, timer, countdown

Is there in Android an efficent way to run a task only for a limited time? Currently I use a Handler with onPostDelayed() and check each run if the current timestamp is higher than my predefined timestamp.

I'm searching for a solution like [CountdownTimer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) but without ticks. I only want define a start and endtime and my task should perform in this period.

Comment: Umm, I fail to see the use case here. What is your "task"? What is it doing during this time, and what should happen when the time is up?

Comment: @ Falmarri: I want to activate the gps receiver, write the location to a log file, and switch off the gps listener after x seconds to save battery. Currently I'm doing that in a service with cascading Handler but I think this is not the most efficient way for doing that in android. I read about AlarmManager, but this is very complicated with combining a service. Falmarri: Do you know what the best way is for solving this problem? Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

If I want to run a task for a specific time I save the time it starts into a 'long' like so:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

And then simply check how long it has been since the task started (assuming it is a loop of some kind) while it is running so if I wanted to run something for 5 seconds:

```
long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
int runtime=5000;//in milliseconds
do
{
    //enter your code here
}while (now+runtime<System.currentTimeMillis());
```